# Regular Expression to match string inside the brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need a javascript regex solution to match the specific text inside this string.

var stirng = "[[http://www.example.com/path/image.jpg, (default)], [, (medium)], [something, (large)]]";

my expectation to get these values as a results http://www.example.com/path/image.jpg ,"" , something

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The regex:

```
/\[([^,]*)/g
```

will do it with the following code:

```js
var sInput = '[http://www.example.com/path/image.jpg, (default)], [, (medium)], [something, (large)]',
    re = /\[([^,]*)/g,
    m;

while(m=re.exec(sInput))
  document.write('"' + m[1] + '"<br/>');
```